# How much traction does your StackApp get?

Tags: discussion, stackapps

How much traction (in terms of for instance sessions per day) does your Stack App get? What have you done to spread the word about your app?

My experience from my first Stack App ([StackRating](https://stackapps.com/questions/6298/stackrating-tracks-skill-of-stack-overflow-users)) is that it's tough to get good traction. I have no idea if I've failed on my idea, or the implementation, or if I simply haven't reached out to enough people.

I posted [two](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/34stbk/stackrating_a_site_that_tracks_skill_of_stack/) [posts](http://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/34su8u/skill_vs_reputation_of_35_million_stackoverflow/) on Reddit, one [post on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255830/has-anyone-tried-to-estimate-stack-overflow-users-skill-by-analyzing-the-data-du/255831) and announced my app here at Stack Apps. Got some traction the first 2 days, and then it basically flatlined:

[image]

Please share your experience and advice.

Comment: Welcome to the lonely, "Long tail".     ... Perhaps you will be hailed as a genius a few years after your death? :)   ... Seriously, if you can fill a need on [metase] you might get some more momentum. Maybe.

Comment: Haha, yes maybe :-D (I'm hoping that it's thanks to something more "important" than StackRating though heheh) I did in fact post on Meta (no idea why I forgot to mention that), but thanks for the tip! Post updated.

Comment: I think it also highly depends on the "stickyness" of your app.  E.g. for me, seeing a rating number is a one-time event... then I move on.  Even a site like Klout that measures your "social media" rating over time gets really boring unless there is a lot of movement. I think the stickyness would increase if there is/was a reason to use the app several times a week.

Comment: Good point. The ratings are in fact "live" so they change as you post new answers. And the position in the rating list is more volatile than the position in the reputation list as far as I can tell.